# Confused about the button inputs for MvC2 on PS2

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-2

So, because I was very interested in this game a while back and remembered it recently, I decided to get the PS2 version and load it up on an emulator to play. I love this game, but I am so stupid at this one thing about it and every 2D fighter I've ever played. It's the friggin inputs.

I grew up on games like Smash Bros., so I never understood the whole thing with these "tap down and then press X" or whatever fighters. This game is especially confusing with the whole punch and kick thing. I don't understand the thing with there being 2 punches and 2 kicks, and how in the hell aerial combos work.

In particular, I'm on the PS2 version, so to narrow my question down: **what the hell do these motions mean?**
[image: mvc2 input]

First off, what is this Z motion? My brother thought it was forward backward forward, but I tried it and it did nothing.

Also, what the everloving hell do I do with that 3rd one? Press left and do a 180 on the bottom? I only managed to do this thing once, and I don't know how.

What's an easy way to remember these inputs also? I forget them everytime and when I do, I end up screwing up the input and do normal attacks. It's almost like it just doesn't work when I try. These seem tricky as balls to do, even when I have the list up. Is there a way to just remember the motion, and what is a good trick to remember them?

Either way, I'm very confused about just this. Very hard to enjoy the game when I can't play it properly :c

Hope you guys can help me out with this. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Z motions mean hitting right, then down, then right AND THEN a punch button (opposite for when your character is on the right side of the screen).Punch button meaning any button you hit, your character throws a punch and same goes with kicks. You have to do this in a relatively fast motion.

MvC two has two punch buttons and two kick buttons. So in your case, to do the second move, you have to hit down, down+foward, then foward and then two punches. Because this game was designed in the arcade era, hitting two punch buttons at once was much easier than a PS2 controller.

The third move on the list you mention requires you to hit left, then left+down, then down, then right+down, then right and two kick buttons. You can tell if you did it wrong if just a kick button comes out (it will usually mean you did it too slow)

Easy way to remember is just practice. Fighting games are a bit hard to figure out at first, which is why these days, fighting game companies like Capcom are trying to make combos easier with each new game. I would recommend going online and looking up bread and butter combos (combos that are easy and essential for the character) and just practice and practice and practice. MvC2 is not an easy game to just pick up play overnight.

If I remember correctly, you can map a button to two punches/kicks.